# Need some cells static in Dynamic Prototype table

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hello In my `TableViewController` I need first three cells static and then dynamic cells. I have done some research and came up that I can do static cells in dynamic table Prototype but not vice versa.

So I drag a tableViewController and choose dynamic prototype and added 4 Prototype Cells(3-static cells. and 1 dynamic) and give each four of them different identifiers and also added the class TableViewCell to all four of them. I have created one TableViewCell class also.

right now I am getting this error

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Here is my code

```
 let NUMBER_OF_STATIC_CELLS = 3
    var labels = ["label1","label2","label3"]

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        return labels.count + 1



    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



        var cell:  TestViewCell!

        print(indexPath.row)
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("static1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TestViewCell


        }

        if (indexPath.row == 1) {
                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("static2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TestViewCell
            //cell.cardSetName?.text = self.cardSetObject["name"] as String
            }

            if (indexPath.row == 2) {
                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("static2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TestViewCell
                //cell.cardSetName?.text = self.cardSetObject["name"] as String
            }





            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TestViewCell
            cell.testLabel.text = "row \(indexPath.row)" // return test rows as set in numberOfRowsInSection


        return cell; //getting error here

    }
```

**UPDATE**

okay error has been removed. Now I come up another problem. I want to know if there are total 4 rows. 3 are static and then rest of them will be dynamic. what would be total number of rows then. I am doing this

```
labels.count+2 //2 static cells(0 1 2 )
```

But I am getting fatal error: Array index out of range

Comment: what is printed out as indexPath.row?

Comment: 0
1
2
3
4 this is what is printing

Comment: Your app crashes when it's 4 because you cell then never gets initialized, in other words, it gets no value and therefore it's nil.

Comment: @Eric so what should I do ?

Comment: @okay eric .. I know only done this.. return labels.count + 2 .. it didn't give me error but another problem comes up

Comment: @Eric I have updated my question

Comment: It will help if you clean up this code. NUMBER_OF_STATIC_CELLS is never used, so remove it. Remove all those extra carriage returns within methods. Fix the indentations in tableView(_, cellForRowAtIndexPath). Remove the numberOfSectionsInTableView() method (you're just returning the default value).

Answer (score 0):

You have no code to return a cell if the row is 4 or more. Change this:

```
if (indexPath.row == 3) {
```

to this:

```
if (indexPath.row >= 3) {
```

Or just change it to:

```
else {
```

Comment: still getting the same error after adding your code

Comment: With the code as it is now the first three "if" tests will do nothing useful. Only the final "cell=" will assign a value to the cell.

Comment: Also,  your question is unclear. Are you asking why you're crashing, or how to "know if there are total 4 rows"?

Answer (score 0):

your code above has some  of errors:

when `indexPath.row == 2` it should be "static 3".

put the last line of the code that defines the "cell" inside an else statement, to stop it from always executing. When you have done that, it should work.
like this:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell: TestViewCell!

        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("static1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TestViewCell
        }

        if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("static2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TestViewCell
        }

        if (indexPath.row == 2) {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("static3", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TestViewCell
        }
        else{
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("dynamic\(indexPath.row-2)", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TestViewCell
        }
        cell.testLabel.text = "row \(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }
```